# What is the subgroup of $C^{*}$ generated by $2i?$

Tags: group-theory

I know $i$ generates $\{1, -1, i, -i\}$, however in this case I get $2i, -4, -8i, 16, 32i, -64, -128i, 256,\dots$ Is it infinite? Why is the group generated by $2i$ so different from the one generated by $i$?

Comment: Don't forget $1, -i/2, -1/4$, and so on. And the short answer is "because $i$ is an element of finite order in $\Bbb C^*$, while $2i$ isn't".

Comment: @Arthur No, it is definitely not nilpotent. It is torsion (i.e. of finite order).

Comment: You're right, and the comment is corrected @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: You might learn something useful if you plot the points $(2i)^n$ in the complex plane and see what happens as $n \to \pm \infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G$ be a (multiplicative) subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^*$ generated by $2i$. If you define $\mathbb{Z}\to G$ by $n\mapsto (2i)^n$ you will quickly see that it is an isomorphism (with addition in $\mathbb{Z}$ and multiplication in $G$) because the kernel is trivial. So yes, it is infinite cyclic.

More generally if $G$ is any group and $g\in G$ then the mapping $\mathbb{Z}\to G$ given by $n\mapsto g^n$ is an epimorphism onto $<g>$. Thus by the first isomorphism theorem the image $<g>$ is isomprhic to $\mathbb{Z}/N$ for some subgroup $N$. In this case $N=\{0\}$ is trivial.

So the reason it is so different from the $i$ case is simply because $i^4=1$ while there is no $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n\neq 0$ such that $(2i)^n=1$ (that's exactly why the kernel is trivial).

Comment: Thank you, it's clear to me now.
So every element except for 1,-1, i,-i will have infinite order, correct?

Comment: @Tam No, every element satisfying $x^n=1$ for some $n$ (i.e. [roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity)) will have a finite order. For example $z=-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ because $z^3=1$. They actually form a dense subset of a unit circle $S^1=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\ \big|\ |z|=1\}$. But not all of them. These are precisely those elements of $S^1$ with "rational" [argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)) $arg(z)=\frac{2\pi}{n}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the map $n\mapsto g^n$ is a monomorphism, or assume that $G$ is cyclic? The image of this map is $\langle g\rangle$ which is all of $G$ if the group is cyclic to start with.

Comment: @SantanaAfton Oops, my mistake. I meant to say $<g>$ is $\mathbb{Z}/N$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is infinite, as you get more and more powers of $2$, as you discovered yourself. 
Why is it different from the group generated by $i$? I guess one answer could be, that $i$ has finite order, therefore generates only a finite group, while $2i$ has infinite order, 'because' $2$ has infinite order.